# Add an ad-hoc primitive tag/annotation to an EObject instance

Tags: eclipse-emf

Consider an EMF EObject instance:

`EObject eObject = ...`

Note that I cannot assume more about `eObject`.

I want to add a `boolean readyToBeProcessed` tag/annotation/property to this and nothing but this `eObject`. This means that none of the other objects managed by the EMF framework which are of the same `.eClass()` should be affected in any way.

Is this possible at all?

The examples I've seen so far either:

1. created a new `EAnnotation` and registered the annotation with the `eObject`'s `eClass()`
2. created a new `EAttribute` and registered the annotation with the `eObject`'s `eClass()`

These approaches, however, modify the `eClass()` which in my case is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to (ab)use adapters, as follows.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Adapter;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Notification;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Notifier;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcoreFactory;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Define an EObject variable and assign it to a random EObject
        EObject eObject = EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEOperation();
        
        ExtraPropertiesAdapter adapter = new ExtraPropertiesAdapter();

        eObject.eAdapters().add(adapter);
        
        // Set the extra readyToBeProcessed "attribute"
        adapter.getProperties().put("readyToBeProcessed", true);
        
        // Get and print the extra readyToBeProcessed attribute
        System.out.println(((ExtraPropertiesAdapter) eObject.eAdapters().
            stream().filter(a -> a instanceof ExtraPropertiesAdapter).findAny().
            orElse(new ExtraPropertiesAdapter())).getProperties().
            get("readyToBeProcessed"));

    }

    public static class ExtraPropertiesAdapter implements Adapter {

        protected HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        public HashMap<String, Object> getProperties() {
            return properties;
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) {}

        @Override
        public Notifier getTarget() { return null; }

        @Override
        public void setTarget(Notifier newTarget) {}

        @Override
        public boolean isAdapterForType(Object type) { return false; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to manage it on the side.

So for a model-based approach I would create another kind of model serialized alongside your existing one.
If you only need simple properties such as booleans and strings, I would simply create a properties file alongside the model resource.